# How do I set a custom token for a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have tried putting c.NotebookApp.token = 'test' but that doesn't work and instead treats it like an empty string so the notebook requires no auth.

Answer (score 29):

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token=abcd
```

note: ABCD doesn't seem to work. I think it must be lowercase hexadecimal

Comment: Using `NotebookApp` is deprecated, you should `ServerApp`. `abcd` as a token is too short and is ignored.

Then, for example: `jupyter notebook --ServerApp.token=f9a3bd4e9f2c3be01cd629154cfb224c2703181e050254b5`

Comment: It is worth noting that if you pass the token in command line arguments, it may be visible in process listing.

Comment: Using `ServerApp` is apparently [deprecated as well now](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other/full-config.html) and `--IdentityProvider.token` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late, but hopefully still helpful.

If you want to put a string you can use the c.NotebookApp.password field instead. This way you can set an arbitrary password to access your notebook.

Though, ideally you should hash the password first so it is not discoverable in the config file (or script if you are using command line arguments).

You can hash a password within Python using:

```
from notebook.auth import passwd
passwd()
```

This will ask you for a password in the prompt and output a hashed password that you can later set in the config file:

```
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed'
```

From the [Jupyter documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#preparing-a-hashed-password)